# jquery.post() not redirecting to view in Rails, yet being processed by controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

My Rails app uses the **jquery.post()** method to send some data from a "clickable" map marker to a controller in my application as seen below.

While the form field functions as normal (i.e. posts to controller and redirects to view), the clickable map marker **only POSTs to controller and does NOT redirect to the specified view**:

### [image]

**The server responses for the posts look like this**

```
//--> THIS IS THE JQUERY 'POST' FROM THE MAP CLICK EVENT. DOES NOT REFRESH THE VIEW
Started POST "/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-26 09:22:20 -0500
  Processing by SearchController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"search"=>"The Hilton Club New York"}
Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 4.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

//--> THIS IS THE RAILS FORM POST. THIS REDIRECTS TO 'index.html.haml'
Started POST "/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-26 09:24:50 -0500
  Processing by SearchController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zjnYqbCB2iEob9g25310tYgZRRuF/WPTwplf92Rho0o=", "search"=>"Hilton Hotel, Avenue of the Americas, New York, NY", "commit"=>"GO"}
Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 5.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**The Javascript looks like this**

```
$.post("/index", {search: place.name},"data","html")
```

**The Rails controller code looks like this**

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {render :text => "You searched for : #{params[:search]}"}
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are not handling the ajax response at all and making an ajax request to a page that you know will redirect is kind of useless.

Comment: OK, then help me answer the "question behind the question". How do I post the results to the controller the same way as I would the form? What am I missing here?

Comment: Well why do you wanna redirect with ajax anyway? You just spit out some json from the server and update your html. Meaning, your server must detect if it's an ajax request (from header or adding a parameter like ajax=1) and respond differently.

Comment: I have a big JSON string already called "place". I want to send part of that string to my "Search" controller and display it on the "Index" view/page. Forget the JS I wrote, how do you do accomplish that?

Comment: Maybe we could simplify - ROR and the MVC you are using in the server doesn't matter to javascript. All that matters is what your server responds, i.e. a string. So your server responds with a JSON string, that javascript can then parse and use. It's however not clear what you want to do, redirecting with ajax doesn't make any sense.

Comment: That's why I said forget "redirecting with ajax". I'm a JS n00b. I have a controller (Search) in my app that responds to input params from either a #1)form or #2) a map 'click' and displays results on a new view (i.e. Search#Index). The form sends the params to the controller and then renders a new view with the result. The map 'click' doesn't. I need to know how to accomplish this.

Comment: If you want to make the map click do the same thing as a form post, have the "click" handler simply post the form by calling the ".submit()" function on the `<form>` DOM element.

Comment: like @pointy said, you simply want to submit the form. So: 1. user clicks on map 2. You set the place parameter in the form by javascript to the place clicked in the map 3. you submit the form via javascript using `.submit()`

Comment: This works, just trying to figure out how to send the whole "place" param from the autocomplete now. I think I'm on the right track!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument to "$.post()" is supposed to be a function, one that's to be called when the HTTP request is finished.  The library will pass the returned content to that function.

Without a function there, whatever the server returns is simply ignored; the library cannot have any idea what to do with it.

Even then, as @Esailija notes in a comment, if your server is issuing a redirect anyway it's not a good fit for ajax in the first place.

Comment: OK, then what do you recommend? Why would I need a funtion when all I want to do is POST the "search" param data (which I already have) to the controller in the same way the form posts? What am I missing here?

Comment: To clarify, I already have a huge JSON hash called "place". It's sitting there, waiting to be send to the controller. I just want to send it to the controller in a POST the same way that a form sends data to the controller in a POST

Comment: Well you *can* post it, but the point is that unless *you* write code to do something when the post is complete, neither jQuery nor your browser will do anything.  That's the whole point of AJAX - your code is completely in control.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are only responding to format.html

Add a format.js (or format.json, I forgot which one) and write some code to handle that case, too.